# Since a dipole has some potential energy,it should be able to do some work !? What is it?

Tags: energy, electrostatics, potential, dipole

We say a dipole has potential energy.What work can a dipole do ?.For eg : A ball on a shelf has a PE because it has the potential to fall down and do some work on the ground if shelf wasnt there.What is this thing here? in case of dipole!!?

Answer (score 1):

The mass of a ball is scalar. Its potential energy is stored in its position in a gravitation field.

A dipole has its potential energy in its *orientation* with regards to  an external field. It can do work by exerting torque when orienting along the field.